# Asp.net How to make a table get a decision data based on Date column Value

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi guys i do have some aspx lines of codes below and i wanted to make a decision of a date meaning if a particular date is gonna be extended after the date values saved in the database in a date column the following should show..

```
<ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <th><%# Eval("C_Id") %></th>
                        <td><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Description") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Price") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Qty") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Date") %></td>


               <td> <%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Date")) > 'Todays Date' ? "<a  href=\"#\"  style=\"padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px; background-color:red \" class=\"badge\" readonly>Due</a>" : "<a  href=\"#\"  style=\"padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px; background-color:green \" class=\"badge\" readonly>Paid</a>" %></td>
```

so where am stacking is here

```
<td> <%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Date")) > 'Todays Date' ?
```

what Should I suppose to do here at the `"Date"` Column and `'Todays Date' so that i can proceed..Any help please I will be greatfull.

Answer (score 3):

Why you use `Convert.ToInt32` for a `DateTime` column? Maybe this works:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Date")).Date > DateTime.Today
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, it worked so much you saved my day  :)

Comment: @DeviceGich click the gray tick at the left side in order to mark this reply as accepted answer.